# jquery slider animation for first and last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

**I want a condition so that slider does not animate to left and right for first and last li.. Currently when you click left you will see the left part goes blank as it will animate the condition of left click and same for right li last child when it reaches there it will still slide to right creating blank space. Below is my code. **

```js
var container = $(".carousel_wrapper");
        var runner = container.find('ul');
        var liWidth = runner.find('li:first').outerWidth();
        var itemsPerPage = 6;
        var noofitems = runner.find('li').length;
     
       


        runner.width(noofitems * liWidth);
        container.width(itemsPerPage*liWidth);

        $('.right').click(function() {
        
        $( runner ).animate({ "left": "-=16%" }, "fast" );
        });


        $('.left').click(function() {
        
          
              
          $(runner).animate({ "left": "+=16%" }, "fast" );
             
            
        });
```

```css
ul,li{ margin:0px; padding:0px;}
/**********
Timings
***********/

.DivisonHeader1{ float:left; width: 50%; padding-right: 1%; position: relative;border-right:1px solid #ccc;}
.DivisonHeader1.DivisionNew{ width: 40%;}
.DivisonHeader2.DivisionNew{ width: 60%;}
.DivisonHeader2{ float:left; width: 50%;padding:0 3%;} 
.bgSkyBlue{ background: #E7F5FF;font-family: "BentonSansMedium" !important;    border-color: #000 !important;    border-top: 1px solid #000;}
.DivisonHeader1 .Tablehaed{ font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 0px;}
.DivisonHeader2 .Tablehaed{  margin-bottom: 0px;}
.DivisonHeader1 .Tablehaed .VDname{ width: 35%; padding-left: 0px;}
.DivisonHeader1 .Tablehaed .KPIname{ width: 20%; padding-right: 10px;}
.DivisonHeader1 .Tablehaed .Type{ width: 15%; padding-right: 10px; text-align: center;}
.DivisonHeader1 .Tablehaed .PStaff{ width: 30%; text-align: center;}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .SymbolPlus{width: 3%}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .MainSubHeading{width: 97%; border-bottom: none;}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .MainSubHeading .Mainheadp1{width: 100%}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .MainSubHeading .Mainheadp1 .Texttual{ margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 17px; font-size: 14px;}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .PointsCheck{ display: inline-block;}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .PointsCheck .CheckPoints.TimingCheckPoints{ display: inline-block; margin-top: 0px;}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .PointsCheck .CheckPoints.TimingCheckPoints:last-child{ border: none;}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .PointsCheck .CheckPoints .VdTableBc { display: inline-block; float: left;    padding-bottom: 0px; border-bottom: 0px;}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .PointsCheck .CheckPoints .VdTableBc div{ display: inline-block; float: left;}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .PointsCheck .CheckPoints .VdTableBc div.BgImprovedRange{ padding: 0px;}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .PointsCheck .CheckPoints .VdTableBc div.Type{ padding-top: 23px;}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .PointsCheck .CheckPoints .VdTableBc div.KPIname{ padding-top: 23px;}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .PointsCheck .CheckPoints .VdTableBc div.VDname{ padding: 5px 0;}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .VD_cons .SelectedVdHeads{ width: 30%;}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .VD_cons .improvedRange{ width: 100%;}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .VD_cons .SelectedVdHeads .InputtextIR{ width: 50%; margin-right: 0px; float: left;}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .PointsCheck .CheckPoints .VdTableBc div.InputtextIR{width: 50%; margin-right: 0px; float: left; background: #f2f2f2; border-right:3px solid #fff; padding: 28px 0;}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen .PointsCheck .CheckPoints .VdTableBc div.InputtextIR.darkerV{background: #eaeaea; border-right: 0px;}
.TablehaedYear{ float:left; width: 100%; position: relative;}
.TablehaedYear .yearsDiv{ width: 100%;font-family: "BentonSansMedium"; text-align: center;padding-bottom: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;font-size: 14px; float:left;}
.TablehaedYear.TableHeadYearDivs .Row1 .yearsDiv{ border-bottom: 0px solid #000;}
.TablehaedYear.TableHeadYearDivs{ border-bottom: none;}
.TablehaedYear.TableHeadYearDivs .Row1{ border-bottom: 1px solid #000; float:left; width: 100%;}
.yearsDiv1 input{ width: 70%; margin: 0px auto; display: block; border: 1px solid #000; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center;}
.TextValueDisplay{ float: left; width: 100%; text-align: center;    text-transform: uppercase;}
.YearsDivArea{ float: left; width: 100%;    padding-top: 12px; font-size: 13px;z-index: 10; position: inherit; top: auto;}
.YearsDivArea.TopAbs{    top: 275px;}
.EditHeader{ position: relative; float: right;    }
.yearsDiv .YearHeader{ display: block; border-bottom:1px solid #000; padding: 2.5px 0;    font-size: 15px; line-height: 17px;}
.TablehaedYear.TableHeadDBT .yearsDiv .YearHeader{ border-width: 2px; line-height: 18px; font-size: 14px;}
.TablehaedYear.TableHeadDBT .yearsDiv .yearsDiv1 .TextValueDisplay{ text-transform: lowercase;}
.yearsDiv .YearHeader{margin-bottom: 41px;}

.yearsDiv1{float: left;width: 100%;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;padding: 8px 0 9px 0;}
.DivisonHeaaderPositionSet{ position: relative; float: left; width: 100%;}
.TablehaedYear.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev{ position: absolute; left: -40px; top: 40%; background: url(../images/Slider_arrow_left1.png); height: 50px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;    width: 50px;}
.TablehaedYear.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next{ position: absolute; right: -40px; top: 40%; background: url(../images/Slider_arrow_right1.png); height: 50px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;    width:50px;}
.ValueSpreads{ float: left; width: 100%;font-family: "BentonSansMedium"; font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 20px;}
.ValueSpreads span{font-family: "BentonSansReg";font-size: 15px;}
.BenifitsCal{ float: left; width: 100%; padding: 10px 0; border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;margin-top: 20px;}
.BenifitsCal .BenifitsHeading{ font-size: 16px;}
.BenifitsCalNoPad.totalb .BenifitsHeading{  font-size: 15px; color: rgb(15,170,255);}

.BenifitsCalNoPad.totalb .BenifitsDivison1 , .BenifitsCalNoPad.totalb .BenifitsDivison2{  font-size: 15px;font-family: "BentonSansMedium";}
.BenifitsCalNoPad{ float: left; width: 100%; padding: 7px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}
.BenifitsCalNoPad.totalb{ border-color:#000;}

.BenifitsCalNoPad.reccuringb{ border-color:#949494; padding-left: 10px;}
.BenifitsHeading{ float: left; width:40%;font-family: "BentonSansMedium"; padding-right: 20px;}
.BenifitsCalNoPad.SimpleRightText .BenifitsHeading{   text-align: right;font-family: "BentonSansReg";}
.BenifitsDivison{ float: left; width: 60%}
.BenifitsDivison1, .BenifitsDivison2{ float: left; width: 50%; text-align: center;}
.yearsDiv .YearHeader.NomargVS{ margin-bottom: 0px;}
.yearsDiv1.TextBorderSimple{font-family: "BentonSansReg"; border-color:#ccc;  }
.pad-top30{ margin-top: 30px !important;border-top: 0px;}
.scrollpainPoint.BCValueDriver.TimingScreen.BSTable .yearsDiv1{ padding: 7px 0;}
.yearsDiv1.TextBorderSimple.pad-top30{font-family: "BentonSansMedium";border-color:#000; }
.MtopPage{ margin-top: 75px !important;}
.MtopPage1{ margin-top: 25px !important;}

/*structure Change*/
.yearsDivHeaders ul{ float: left; width: 100%; border-bottom: 2px solid #000; padding-bottom: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;    font-family: "BentonSansMedium"; line-height: 16px;}
.yearsDivHeaders ul li{ float: left; width: 100px; text-align: center;}
.carousel_wrapper.yearsDivHeaders{ height: 24px;}
.carousel_wrapper{ float: left; width: 100%; position: relative; height: 56px; overflow: hidden;}
.carousel_wrapper ul{font-family: "BentonSansMedium";position: absolute;    top:0px;     overflow: hidden;}
.carousel_wrapper li{ float: left; width: 100px;}
.carousel_wrapper li span.TextValueDisplay{ text-transform: lowercase;}
.carousel_wrapper li  input{  width: 70%; margin: 0px auto; display: block; border: 1px solid #000; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center;}
.FullRowAll{ border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; float:left; width: 100%;}

.NewimingHeadDivision .VD_cons{  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(194,229,255);}
.next{ float: right; position: relative;}
.next a{ position: absolute; top:-200px;  width: 53px; height: 52px; font-size: 0px; z-index: 100;}
.next a.left{ left: 0px;background: url(../images/Slider_arrow_left1.png);}
.next a.right{ right: -40px;background: url(../images/Slider_arrow_right1.png);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="DivisonHeader2">
  <div class="TablehaedYear">
    <div class="carousel_wrapper yearsDivHeaders">
      <ul>
        <li><span>Year 1</span> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Year 2</span> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Year 3</span> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Year 4</span> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Year 5</span> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Year 6</span> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Year 7</span> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Year 8</span> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Year 9</span> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Year 10</span> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Year 12</span> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Year 13</span> 
        </li>
        <li><span>Year 14</span> 
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="FullRowAll">
  <div class="DivisonHeader2">
    <div class="carousel_wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li class="nooo"><span class="TextValueDisplay">xx1</span>
          <input type="text" value="xx%">
        </li>
        <li><span class="TextValueDisplay">xx1</span>
          <input type="text" value="xx%">
        </li>
        <li><span class="TextValueDisplay">xx1</span>
          <input type="text" value="xx%">
        </li>
        <li><span class="TextValueDisplay">xx1</span>
          <input type="text" value="xx%">
        </li>
        <li><span class="TextValueDisplay">xx1</span>
          <input type="text" value="xx%">
        </li>
        <li><span class="TextValueDisplay">xx1</span>
          <input type="text" value="xx%">
        </li>
        <li><span class="TextValueDisplay">xx1</span>
          <input type="text" value="xx%">
        </li>
        <li><span class="TextValueDisplay">xx1</span>
          <input type="text" value="xx%">
        </li>
        <li><span class="TextValueDisplay">xx1</span>
          <input type="text" value="xx%">
        </li>
        <li><span class="TextValueDisplay">xx1</span>
          <input type="text" value="xx%">
        </li>
        <li><span class="TextValueDisplay">xx1</span>
          <input type="text" value="xx%">
        </li>
        <li><span class="TextValueDisplay">xx1</span>
          <input type="text" value="xx%">
        </li>
        <li><span class="TextValueDisplay">xx1</span>
          <input type="text" value="xx%">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="container">
  <!---------Slide Arrows-------->
  <div class=" DivisonHeader2">
    <a href="#" class="left">left</a>
    <a href="#" class="right">right</a>
  </div>

</div>
<!---------Slide Arrows-------->
```

Comment: just disable the left/right buttons when they reach their corresponding end points?

Comment: I cant disable them.. They will be shown all the time.. I just want to disable sliding effect when they reach extreme left/right positions. What jquery condition i need to add on this?

Comment: Dont see the css.. Thats just for demo purpose. I need the jquery code.

Comment: You're always calling `$( runner ).animate({ "left": "-=16%" }, "fast" );` whenever it's clicked. All you have to do is checked whether they are at their end points or not before running it. Just add an if statement of some sort.

Comment: Actually i am newbie to jquery can you provide me that check.?

Comment: @roko C. Buljan I want to show only 6 elements so thats why width is 16.666% and yes always.

Comment: For the left side you can just do a `if ($(runner).css("left") != "0px")`. You will have to work out how you want to do the right side as your slider doesn't properly match the lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of animating `left` animate the `scrollLeft` property:

[jsFiddle demo with multiple carousels](https://jsfiddle.net/sdpcuLnu/)

```js
$(".carousel").each(function() {

  var $ul = $("ul", this),
      ul = $ul[0],
      $li = $ul.find("li");
  
  $(".prev, .next", this).on("click", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if($ul.is(":animated")) return; // Don't register clicks if it's animating
    var isNext = $(this).is(".next"),
        w = $li.width();
    $ul.animate({scrollLeft: "+="+ (isNext ? w : -w) }, 320);
  });

});
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}


/*
* CAROUSEL
* Styles essential just for the carousel
*/

.carousel > ul{
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.carousel > ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: normal;
  margin-right: -4px;
  width: 16.666%;
}

/* your custom styles here */
.carousel > ul li{
  text-align: center;
}
.carousel span.title{
  display:block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
.carousel span.tag{
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="carousel">
  
  <ul>
    <li><span class="title">Year 1</span>xx1<br><span class="tag">xx%</span></li>  
    <li><span class="title">Year 2</span>xx1<br><span class="tag">xx%</span></li>
    <li><span class="title">Year 3</span>xx1<br><span class="tag">xx%</span></li>
    <li><span class="title">Year 4</span>xx1<br><span class="tag">xx%</span></li>
    <li><span class="title">Year 5</span>xx1<br><span class="tag">xx%</span></li>
    <li><span class="title">Year 6</span>xx1<br><span class="tag">xx%</span></li>
    <li><span class="title">Year 7</span>xx1<br><span class="tag">xx%</span></li>
    <li><span class="title">Year 8</span>xx1<br><span class="tag">xx%</span></li>
    <li><span class="title">Year 9</span>xx1<br><span class="tag">xx%</span></li>
    <li><span class="title">Year 10</span>xx1<br><span class="tag">xx%</span></li>
    <li><span class="title">Year 11</span>xx1<br><span class="tag">xx%</span></li>
    <li><span class="title">Year 12</span>xx1<br><span class="tag">xx%</span></li>
    <li><span class="title">Year 13</span>xx1<br><span class="tag">xx%</span></li>
  </ul>

  <button class="prev">&larr;</button>
  <button class="next">&rarr;</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is really good .But  I will be having multiple carousels with only one left right button.. How to do that?

Comment: @sahildhir No worries. my code will handle multiple carousels. (Thx btw :) )

Comment: I need multiple carousel but only one control button[one prev and one next] to handle all left/right slide movement.

Comment: @sahildhir than modify this variable to match your selectors `var $ul = $("ul", this),`